# Is there localization beyond language?

Tags: localization

I am wondering, if there are any situations, when it is necessary to localize a system (especially: online system) at a level below language.

Usually, localization regards two levels:

- country
- language (if multiple used in a country)

Then it goes down to regionalization (I mean: displaying content relevant to some administrative part of a country, be it district, city, voyvodship in my beautiful country or anything else).

My question is:
**When (if) it is necessary to localize an online system due to some internal division of the society (religious, cultural or national in multi-nationality countries, but *not just regional)*.**

I mean something more than just content profiling, of course. Something that would manifest as a "choose your group" field.

Answer (score 2):

Beyond language, localization includes language but also cultural relevance (ie pop culture references, jargon). Images also may need to be changed (ie an image of a woman in sleeveless dress in some countries would be offensive).

Other related things that may affect your content and site design based on locale: 
masculine / feminine roles, 
collectivist / individualistic identity of the visitor
uncertainty avoidance / risk-taking
etc.
(I'm sure there are many other dimensions that I have failed to mention. Many of these from [The Culturally Customized Web Site](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0750678496))

The question about when it's necessary to localize an online system due to internal divisions is completely in context of whatever your system is attempting to do:

- Is there something about your content that justifies making the distinction at this level?
- If so, do the internal divisions have a commonly accepted way of expressing these that would be easily recognized if presented to users?
- Is the business value of having these distinctions high enough to justify the expense and effort needed to create and maintain the various versions of content?

While I haven't done what you describe, I would suggest approaching the problem not by divisions of society but perhaps as personalization ("More like this" etc is a common approach to tailor a system to the visitor). Similarly, taking care to eliminate the need for such level of regional variety seems like a much better path unless you have very specific goals that would require doing so.

Comment: Color is also very important. For instance, unless I'm mistaken, Red is considered as good/positive for Japanese culture.